# Predicting curves within a field with Accord.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, accord.net

In an X and Y axis I have a field constrained by a min and a max curve. Within that field there can be an infinite amount of potential curves. I need to predict how the curve crossing a given x,y point within that field will look like.

[image]

In the image above the orange curves cross given x,y points (blue, grey, purple).

My base data is basically a collection (~100) of the following set:

- A given x (double)
- A given y (double)
- The cross curve's x values as an array of doubles
- The cross curve's y values as an array of doubles

How can I model this in accord.NET to predict a curve within this field for any x,y?

Which algorithm(s) from the library should I use to achieve my goal?